# ASP Web Forms: A method to calculate a decimal raised to the power another decimal value?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, exponent

How can I find the value of a decimal value raised to the power another decimal value? For example, I want to find the value of:

```
12.25^2.5
```

To elaborate on the issue, I am building a ASP Web Form in which I will be reading two decimal (double datatype) values through TextBoxes and return the value of the first number raised to the power second number.

Comment: Using Math.Pow ?

Comment: @BadMiscuit % is for modulus, not power.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry I read too quickly the question, I thought he wanted the decimal part of the result. I edited the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in a junior level at ASP.NET and C# but that's the code I would use:

```
double firstNumber = Convert.Double(TextBox1.Text);
double secondNumber = Convert.Double(TextBox2.Text);
OutputTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Pow(firstNumber,secondNumber));
```

Try it and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C# (you haven't said, but if not you can easily convert it to another language), then what you need is the `Math.Pow` method:

```
double result, input1, input2; 
input1 = Double.Parse(yourFirstTextBox.Text);
input2 = Double.Parse(yourSecondTextBox.Text);
result = Math.Pow(input1, input2);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx